# How to handle paging requirement in ASP.NET MVC Razor View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, pagination

I have a controller action which passes a list of products to the view. There can be zero, single or any number of products in the list. What I want is that if the products are more than 10, pagination should occur.

I have no idea whatsover as how to do this thing. Currently i am just passing the list to view in the controller like following::

```
    public ActionResult Catalog(string id)
    {
        Category catalog = pe.Categories.Where(cat => cat.CategoryName == id).Single();
        return View(catalog);
    }
```

And then running the foreach in the view ::

```
        @foreach (var cat in Model.Products)
        {
            .
            .
        }
```

I have removed the code between the foreach for brevity.

Please tell me how to handle the pagination for such scenarios. Earlier i used server controls in regular asp.net so didn't required to worry about the HTML and such matters. MVC and Razor are pretty new for me and i am trying to get accustomed.

Comment: you can try this working code [https://stackoverflow.com/a/49872052/1960720](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49872052/1960720)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). Or using [MvcContrib Grid](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/08/asp-net-mvc-paging-sorting-filtering-using-the-mvccontrib-grid-and-pager.aspx). Or even [doing it manually](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2008/08/27/paging-with-aspnet-mvc/).

Comment: Thanks Darin. First, I will try to hook it up manually so that i am able to get a hold on with Razor and HTML :-) . Then will use check MvcContrib .

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay, that's a very nice approach. Understanding the inner workings is always best before using some ready to use out of the box controls without understanding how they work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nuget package called PagedList that makes this dead simple.

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/PagedList

Answer (score 0):

Since https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList is no longer maintained I suggest that you try https://github.com/kpi-ua/X.PagedList which is a fork of that same project but with the main difference being that X.PagedList is portable assembly. It means, that you can use it not only in Web projects, but also in Winforms, Window Phone, Silverlight and etc. projects."

To install it using Nuget Package Manager Console run this command

```
PM> Install-Package X.PagedList.Mvc
```

**IMPORTANT: Running the previous command will try to install JQuery 2.0 and other dependencies build by microsoft**

And follow the steps mentioned on 
https://github.com/kpi-ua/X.PagedList

**/Controllers/ProductController.cs**

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public object Index(int? page)
    {
        var products = MyProductDataSource.FindAllProducts(); //returns IQueryable<Product> representing an unknown number of products. a thousand maybe?

        var pageNumber = page ?? 1; // if no page was specified in the querystring, default to the first page (1)
        var onePageOfProducts = products.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25); // will only contain 25 products max because of the pageSize

        ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts = onePageOfProducts;
        return View();
    }
}
```

**/Views/Products/Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Product Listing"
}
@using PagedList.Mvc; //import this so we get our HTML Helper
@using PagedList; //import this so we can cast our list to IPagedList (only necessary because ViewBag is dynamic)

<!-- import the included stylesheet for some (very basic) default styling -->
<link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- loop through each of your products and display it however you want. we're just printing the name here -->
<h2>List of Products</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach(var product in ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts){
        <li>@product.Name</li>
    }
</ul>

<!-- output a paging control that lets the user navigation to the previous page, next page, etc -->
@Html.PagedListPager( (IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }) )
```

Other still working links include:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2008/08/27/paging-with-aspnet-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

To show the title ---> Topaging + DisplayNameFor
just add bellow code for each column in View

```
<th>
```

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.First().LastName)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create paging on Razor view, here is the working code for that.

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    @{
        int currentPage = ViewBag.Page;
        int staticRange = 11;
        int NoOfPage = 50;
        int Range = staticRange;
        int Start = 1;
        int End = staticRange;
        int Reminder = 0;
        int Divdent = 0;

        if (currentPage >= (Range - 1))
        {
            Reminder = currentPage % 10;
            Divdent = currentPage / 10;

            Start = (Divdent * staticRange) - Divdent;
            Range = Start + staticRange;
            End = Range;
        }
        else
        {
            Range = staticRange;
            Start = 1;
        }

        if (Range >= NoOfPage)
        {
            Range = NoOfPage;
            End = Range;

        }
        if (currentPage == NoOfPage)
        {
            Start = NoOfPage - staticRange +1;

        }
        <div>
            currentPage: @currentPage<br />
            NoOfPage:@NoOfPage <br />
            Range: @Range<br />
            Start:@Start<br />
            End:@End<br />
            Reminder:@Reminder<br />
            Divdent:@Divdent
        </div>
        <ul class="pagination">
            @{
                if (currentPage == 1)
                {
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link disabled" href="javascript:void(0)">Previous</a></li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="@Url.Action("About","Home",new {page=(currentPage>0)?currentPage-1:0 })">Previous</a></li>
                }
            }

            @{

                if (Range > staticRange)
                {

                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="@Url.Action("About","Home",new {page=Start-1 })">...</a></li>
                }
                for (int i = Start; i < End; i++)
                {
                    <li class="page-item @(i==currentPage?"active":"")"><a class="page-link" href="@Url.Action("About","Home",new {page=i })">@i</a></li>

                    if ((i == (Range - 1)) && Range < NoOfPage)
                    {

                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="@Url.Action("About","Home",new {page=End })">...</a></li>
                    }
                }
                <li class="page-item @(NoOfPage==currentPage?"active":"")"><a class="page-link" href="@Url.Action("About","Home",new {page=NoOfPage })">@NoOfPage</a></li>
            }

            @{
                if (currentPage < NoOfPage)
                {
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="@Url.Action("About","Home",new {page=currentPage+1 })">Next</a></li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link disabled" href="javascript:void(0)">Next</a></li>
                }
            }

        </ul>
    }
</nav>
```